# Java jsch sudo shell script not working as expected, Linux, Unix

Tags: java, linux, shell, jsch

I have a shell script containing start and status methods.

When I run start method  **manually** from the shell the command will be like

```
sudo -u x /y.sh start
```

Output will be `Process has started`.
After that if I run status method from shell the command will be like

```
sudo -u x /y.sh status
```

Output will be `Process is running`

If I run the shell script  using **Jsch sudo class** 
When running start method
I am getting output as `Process has started`
After that I run the status method I am getting the output as
`Process is not running` instead of `Process is running` as we started the process using start.

How to make the status start from Jsch?
Please suggest me....

I am placing the shell script code here

Comment: You need to supply more useful information. We don't know anything about this process that you're trying to start. We don't have the jsch code that you're using to run these commands. We can't see this getpid shell function that is apparently failing to find the running process. Is the process actually not running, or is the "status" operation just unable to see the running process?

Comment: The process is not actually running. I have added the code of getpid and jsch sudo. Thanks for your help

Comment: When I run start method secod time, It is actually removing the stale PID of earlier start by displaying message    Starting processor 4   ...
Removed stale pid file: 
Started processor 4

Comment: It's under status method